# How to define .this in a functional component

Tags: reactjs

I am working with functional components and I currently transfer some code from a class-based component. The original component has the code `const { publisherId } = this;` However I can't use that for my functional component? Do I even need that check in a functional component?

```
createPublisher() {
    this.publisherId = uuid();
    const { publisherId } = this;

    const publisher = OT.initPublisher(container, properties, (err) => {
      if (publisherId !== this.publisherId) {
        // Either this publisher has been recreated or the
        // component unmounted so don't invoke any callbacks
        return;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's how they made it in the example I am currently trying to understand and replicate.

Comment: React functional components are instanceless, i.e. no `this`. Perhaps it would be helpful to include *your* functional component code. The above isn't even a component so it's hard to know what you're even trying to do.

Comment: Hi Drew, the full code for the component can be seen here: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react/blob/master/src/OTPublisher.js

That class-based component I am rewriting in a functional-component. However, that part mentioned above confuses me.

Comment: Ok, sounds more like your question is actually "How to convert this class-based component to a functional component" then. The answer to your current question is simply that you can't use `this`. If you want to, and can, please update your question to reflect react component type conversion and include your functional component as well as the link to the class-based component you are trying to convert.